# creating a using with package template types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that is passed an arbitrary number of template arguments. And i want to create a using that will store them all

I thought for a long time and did not find a suitable answer

```
template <typename... Ts>
class TypeSet {
  using T = Ts; // something like that
}

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto return_unique() {
   // something to create TypeSet<NewTs...> set
   return set;
}

// return_unique<int, int> -->  TypeSet<int>

template <typename... Ts>
class myobj {
   using unique_template = return_unique<Ts...>()::T;
}
```

Comment: Provide specialization for [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_element) and [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_size)?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with the new `T`  that you can't use `Ts` for?

Comment: I have a template function that will return a TypeSet object with template values ​​without repetition. I want to get a package of these template parameters

Comment: @Alex How would you use `T` if the above `using T = Ts;` had worked? Can you update the question to show that?

Comment: Ok, so `return_unique` should create a `TypeSet` where all types in `NewTs` are unique types? I don't see what `T` in `TypeSet` is supposed to be used for though.

Comment: yes. for example return_unique<int, int, float> -->  TypeSet<int, float>

Comment: I eventually need to get rid of this auxiliary structure TypeSet and get only the parameters.  
i.e. unique_template should have NewTs...

Comment: @Alex _"and get only the parameters. i.e. unique_template should have NewTs..."_ - that can't be done. I think I've seen a proposal to add that to the language, but afaik, it's not even in C++23.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a class that is passed an arbitrary number of template arguments. And i want to create a using that will store them all
>
> I have a template function that will return a TypeSet object with template values ​​without repetition. I want to get a package of these template parameters
>
> for example `return_unique<int, int, float>` --> `TypeSet<int, float>`

Let's use the `TypeSet` you already have, with one adjustment: we don't need the `using T` part.

This should do:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct TypeSet{};
```

Now we need a way to check if *any* type `T` exists in a given `TypeSet`. I will introduce a check `Any` for now - later we will see how this can be replaced by a one-liner.

Let's start with the *false* case:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class ... Ts>
struct Any : std::false_type {};
```

This will be the fallback case for when the following cases "fail":

The *true* case: there is a `T` at the head of the `TypeSet`

```
template <class T, class ... Ts>
struct Any<T, TypeSet<T, Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

And finally: no `T` at the head of `TypeSet` ? Check the tail

```
template <class T, class U, class ... Ts>
struct Any<T, TypeSet<U, Ts...>> : Any<T, TypeSet<Ts...>> {};
```

---

With this in place, we can implement your *unique*. One way to implement it is by taking out an element `T` one by one from the given list into an internal list (lets call it `L`) if `!Any<T, L>::value`:

Let's start with the base case:

```
template <class /* To */, class ... /* From */>
struct Unique_impl;

template <class ... Ts>
struct Unique_impl<TypeSet<Ts...>, TypeSet<>>
{ using type = TypeSet<Ts...>; };
```

i.e if we have exhausted the `From` list, we're left with the `To` list.

And finally

```
template <class T, class ... Ts, class ... Us>
struct Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us...>, TypeSet<T, Ts...>> :
    std::conditional_t
        < Any<T, TypeSet<Us...>>::value                  // T in internal list?
        , Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us...>, TypeSet<Ts...>>    // Yes: We skip it
        , Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us..., T>, TypeSet<Ts...>> // No:  We add it
        >
{};
```

And an alias to make it all more convenient: (notice we give it an empty `TypeSet<>` as our internal list to begin with)

```
template <class T>
using Unique = typename Unique_impl<TypeSet<>, T>::type;
```

---

Now we just have to confirm that it work:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Unique<TypeSet<int,int,float>>, TypeSet<int,float>>);
```

---

Edit: Thanks to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) for great comment

> `Any<T, TypeSet<Us...>>::value` can be replaced by `(std::is_same_v<T, Us> || ...)`

Saving us lines of code - we end up with

```
template <class T, class ... Ts, class ... Us>
struct Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us...>, TypeSet<T, Ts...>> :
    std::conditional_t
        < (std::is_same_v<T, Us> || ...)                 // T in internal list?
        , Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us...>, TypeSet<Ts...>>    // Yes: We skip it
        , Unique_impl<TypeSet<Us..., T>, TypeSet<Ts...>> // No:  We add it
        >
{};
```

Comment: `Any<T, TypeSet<Us...>>::value` can be replaced by `(std::is_same_v<T, Us> || ...)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 delightful!

Answer (score 2):

Given a `X = TypeSet<T...>`, you can get back `T...` as a parameter pack like this:

```cpp
[]<typename... T>(TypeSet<T...>) { /* Use T... in here*/ }(X{})
```

You can also store them in a `std::tuple`: `using T = std::tuple<Ts...>;`. Or, again, you can use `TypeSet` itself to hold the types: `using T = TypeSet<Ts...>`.

Comment: I would like to pass then parameters from using to variant. can i do it somehow?

Comment: @Alex Wouldn't that just be `using variant_type = std::variant<Ts...>;` ?

Comment: I write my analogue of the variant and the TypeSet structure in the end should return a package of templates without repetition.

Comment: @Alex I'm afraid I don't understand. Perhaps you could clarify your question with some examples of `TypeSet`s and how you plan to use them?

Comment: @Alex `using variant_type = decltype([]<typename... T>(TypeSet<T...>) -> std::variant<T...> {}(return_unique<Ts...>()));`